# .deb Files Not Installing

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, vivaldi

I have been trying to get Vivaldi to install on my Raspberry Pi, (it worked for a while however I had to reinstall Raspbian because I like to tinker) and when I double click nothing happens. I've tried opening it with Run Software, Autorun Prompt and more. Any ideas?

I use these commands

```
cd Downloads/
wget https://downloads.vivaldi.com/stable/vivaldi-stable_1.13.1008.34-1_armhf.deb
sudo apt install vivaldi-stable_1.13.1008.34-1_armhf.deb
```

Note: I installed Raspbian Lite with the MATE Desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can download the latest **Vivaldi 32bit ARM DEB** from https://vivaldi.com/download/ but recent installations add vivaldi to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` so you should be notified of updates.

You can install Vivaldi from the repository with `apt install vivaldi-stable`

If you want to install the latest from deb use `dpkg -i`

The version you seem to be trying to install is rather old.

On my system I have, although there is a (very recent) later version.

```
apt-cache policy vivaldi-stable
vivaldi-stable:
  Installed: 2.4.1488.40-1
  Candidate: 2.4.1488.40-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.4.1488.40-1 100
```

This was installed from `vivaldi-stable_2.4.1488.40-1_armhf.deb`

---

I downloaded and installed the latest with:-

```
cd Downloads/
wget https://downloads.vivaldi.com/stable/vivaldi-stable_2.5.1525.41-1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i vivaldi-stable_2.5.1525.41-1_armhf.deb
```

Comment: I am a complete noob at using the terminal. What command should I use to install it? I have downloaded the newer version.

Comment: `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/vivaldi-stable_2.5.1525.41-1_armhf.deb`

Comment: this saves me a question, I was wondering if the new vivaldi .deb package was still compatible, because I got the old package pointed to by the blog, not the "latest linux arm" build.  I had to do `sudo --fix-broken install  -y`  to get the old one to work

Answer (score 0):

Well... I found a WiringPi .deb update (up to 2.52 *ONLY* for RPi4B) on the WiringPi source page, with a download link. Brought it into a temp folder adjacent to NOOBS.

The .deb file knew the way... was I just lucky?

$ cd \xxxx (where I dropped the .deb file)

$ sudo dpkg -i wiringpi-xxxxxx.deb

$ gpio -v

( bottom line:
it worked fine)